# Starting .ps1 Script from PowerShell with Parameters and Credentials and getting output using variable

Tags: powershell, runas, start-process

Hello Stack Community :)

I have a simple goal. I'd like to start some PowerShell Script from an another Powershell Script, but there are 3 conditions:

1. I have to pass credentials (the execution connects to a database that has specific user)
2. It has to take some Parameters
3. I'd like to pass the output into a variable

There is a similar question [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60885735/starting-ps1-script-from-powershell-with-parameters-and-credentials-and-getting). But the answer is to use files as a way to communicate between 2 PS Scripts. I just would like to avoid access conflicts. @Update: The Main Script is going to start few other scripts. so the solution with files can be tricky, if the execution will be performed from multiple user at the same time.

**Script1.ps1** is the script that should have string as an output. (Just to be clear, it's a fictive script, the real one has 150 Rows, so I just wanted to make an example)

```
param(  
[String]$DeviceName
)
#Some code that needs special credentials
$a = "Device is: " + $DeviceName
$a
```

**ExecuteScripts.ps1** should invoke that one with those 3 conditions mentioned above

I tried multiple solutions. This one for examplte:

```
$arguments = "C:\..\script1.ps1" + " -ClientName" + $DeviceName
$output = Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList $arguments -Credential $credentials
$output
```

I don't get any output from that and I can't just call the script with

```
&C:\..\script1.ps1 -ClientName PCPC
```

Because I can't pass `-Credential` parameter to it..

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: If this is just about access conflicts: creating _unique filenames_  for every invocation would solve your problem, right?

Comment: @mklement0 if it's the only way, I would stack with that solution. Just generating random file names, checking if such file exists...I will be executing 6 to 10 scripts from my Java Code and it would need 6 to 10 files every time i'm using or someone else uses my application. So its about performance also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note:

- The following solution **works with *any* external program**, and **captures output invariably as *text***.
- To **invoke *another PowerShell instance*** and **capture its output *as rich objects*** (with limitations), see the variant solution in the bottom section or consider [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60890301/45375), which uses the [PowerShell SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/windows-powershell).

Here's a proof-of-concept based on **direct use of the [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process) and [`System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo) .NET types to capture process output *in memory*** (as stated in your question, `Start-Process` is not an option, because it only supports capturing output in *files*, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60887826/45375)):

Note:

- Due to running as a different user, this is supported on *Windows only* (as of .NET Core 3.1), but in both PowerShell editions there.
- Due to needing to run as a different user and needing to capture output, `.WindowStyle` cannot be used to run the command *hidden* (because using `.WindowStyle` requires `.UseShellExecute` to be `$true`, which is incompatible with these requirements); however, since all output is being *captured*, setting `.CreateNoNewWindow` to `$true` effectively results in hidden execution.
- **Only *stdout* output is captured below. If you want to capture *stderr* output too, you'll need to capture it via *events***, because use of `$ps.StandardError.ReadToEnd()` alongside `$ps.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()` could lead to *deadlocks*.

```
# Get the target user's name and password.
$cred = Get-Credential

# Create a ProcessStartInfo instance
# with the relevant properties.
$psi = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo] @{
  # For demo purposes, use a simple `cmd.exe` command that echoes the username. 
  # See the bottom section for a call to `powershell.exe`.
  FileName = 'cmd.exe'
  Arguments = '/c echo %USERNAME%'
  # Set this to a directory that the target user
  # is permitted to access.
  WorkingDirectory = 'C:\'                                                                   #'
  # Ask that output be captured in the
  # .StandardOutput / .StandardError properties of
  # the Process object created later.
  UseShellExecute = $false # must be $false
  RedirectStandardOutput = $true
  RedirectStandardError = $true
  # Uncomment this line if you want the process to run effectively hidden.
  #   CreateNoNewWindow = $true
  # Specify the user identity.
  # Note: If you specify a UPN in .UserName
  # (user@doamin.com), set .Domain to $null
  Domain = $env:USERDOMAIN
  UserName = $cred.UserName
  Password = $cred.Password
}

# Create (launch) the process...
$ps = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($psi)

# Read the captured standard output.
# By reading to the *end*, this implicitly waits for (near) termination
# of the process.
# Do NOT use $ps.WaitForExit() first, as that can result in a deadlock.
$stdout = $ps.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()

# Uncomment the following lines to report the process' exit code.
#   $ps.WaitForExit()
#   "Process exit code: $($ps.ExitCode)"

"Running ``cmd /c echo %USERNAME%`` as user $($cred.UserName) yielded:"
$stdout
```

The above yields something like the following, showing that the process successfully ran with the given user identity:

```
Running `cmd /c echo %USERNAME%` as user jdoe yielded:
jdoe
```

---

Since **you're calling another *PowerShell* instance**, you may want to **take advantage of the [PowerShell CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)'s ability to represent output in CLIXML format, which allows deserializing the output into *rich objects*, albeit with limited type fidelity**, as explained in [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60887826/45375).

```
# Get the target user's name and password.
$cred = Get-Credential

# Create a ProcessStartInfo instance
# with the relevant properties.
$psi = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo] @{
  # Invoke the PowerShell CLI with a simple sample command
  # that calls `Get-Date` to output the current date as a [datetime] instance.
  FileName = 'powershell.exe'
  # `-of xml` asks that the output be returned as CLIXML,
  # a serialization format that allows deserialization into
  # rich objects.
  Arguments = '-of xml -noprofile -c Get-Date'
  # Set this to a directory that the target user
  # is permitted to access.
  WorkingDirectory = 'C:\'                                                                   #'
  # Ask that output be captured in the
  # .StandardOutput / .StandardError properties of
  # the Process object created later.
  UseShellExecute = $false # must be $false
  RedirectStandardOutput = $true
  RedirectStandardError = $true
  # Uncomment this line if you want the process to run effectively hidden.
  #   CreateNoNewWindow = $true
  # Specify the user identity.
  # Note: If you specify a UPN in .UserName
  # (user@doamin.com), set .Domain to $null
  Domain = $env:USERDOMAIN
  UserName = $cred.UserName
  Password = $cred.Password
}

# Create (launch) the process...
$ps = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($psi)

# Read the captured standard output, in CLIXML format,
# stripping the `#` comment line at the top (`#< CLIXML`)
# which the deserializer doesn't know how to handle.
$stdoutCliXml = $ps.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() -replace '^#.*\r?\n'

# Uncomment the following lines to report the process' exit code.
#   $ps.WaitForExit()
#   "Process exit code: $($ps.ExitCode)"

# Use PowerShell's deserialization API to 
# "rehydrate" the objects.
$stdoutObjects = [Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Deserialize($stdoutCliXml)

"Running ``Get-Date`` as user $($cred.UserName) yielded:"
$stdoutObjects
"`nas data type:"
$stdoutObjects.GetType().FullName
```

The above outputs something like the following, showing that the `[datetime]` instance ([`System.DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime)) output by `Get-Date` was deserialized as such:

```
Running `Get-Date` as user jdoe yielded:

Friday, March 27, 2020 6:26:49 PM

as data type:
System.DateTime
```

Answer (score 5):

`Start-Process` would be my *last resort choice* for invoking PowerShell from PowerShell - especially because all I/O becomes strings and not (deserialized) objects.

Two alternatives:

## 1. If the user is a local admin and PSRemoting is configured

If a remote session against the local machine (unfortunately restricted to local admins) is a option, I'd definitely go with `Invoke-Command`:

```
$strings = Invoke-Command -FilePath C:\...\script1.ps1 -ComputerName localhost -Credential $credential
```

`$strings` will contain the results.

---

## 2. If the user is not an admin on the target system

You can write your own "local-only `Invoke-Command`" by spinning up an out-of-process runspace by:

1. Creating a [`PowerShellProcessInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.powershellprocessinstance), under a different login
2. Creating a runspace in said process
3. Execute your code in said out-of-process runspace

I put together such a function below, see inline comments for a walk-through:

```
function Invoke-RunAs
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Alias('PSPath')]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType Leaf})]
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [string]
        ${FilePath},

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [pscredential]
        [System.Management.Automation.CredentialAttribute()]
        ${Credential},

        [Alias('Args')]
        [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments = $true)]
        [System.Object[]]
        ${ArgumentList},

        [Parameter(Position = 1)]
        [System.Collections.IDictionary]
        $NamedArguments
    )

    begin
    {
        # First we set up a separate managed powershell process
        Write-Verbose "Creating PowerShellProcessInstance and runspace"
        $ProcessInstance = [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PowerShellProcessInstance]::new($PSVersionTable.PSVersion, $Credential, $null, $false)

        # And then we create a new runspace in said process
        $Runspace = [runspacefactory]::CreateOutOfProcessRunspace($null, $ProcessInstance)
        $Runspace.Open()
        Write-Verbose "Runspace state is $($Runspace.RunspaceStateInfo)"
    }

    process
    {
        foreach($path in $FilePath){
            Write-Verbose "In process block, Path:'$path'"
            try{
                # Add script file to the code we'll be running
                $powershell = [powershell]::Create([initialsessionstate]::CreateDefault2()).AddCommand((Resolve-Path $path).ProviderPath, $true)

                # Add named param args, if any
                if($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('NamedArguments')){
                    Write-Verbose "Adding named arguments to script"
                    $powershell = $powershell.AddParameters($NamedArguments)
                }

                # Add argument list values if present
                if($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('ArgumentList')){
                    Write-Verbose "Adding unnamed arguments to script"
                    foreach($arg in $ArgumentList){
                        $powershell = $powershell.AddArgument($arg)
                    }
                }

                # Attach to out-of-process runspace
                $powershell.Runspace = $Runspace

                # Invoke, let output bubble up to caller
                $powershell.Invoke()

                if($powershell.HadErrors){
                    foreach($e in $powershell.Streams.Error){
                        Write-Error $e
                    }
                }
            }
            finally{
                # clean up
                if($powershell -is [IDisposable]){
                    $powershell.Dispose()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    end
    {
        foreach($target in $ProcessInstance,$Runspace){
            # clean up
            if($target -is [IDisposable]){
                $target.Dispose()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then use like so:

```
$output = Invoke-RunAs -FilePath C:\path\to\script1.ps1 -Credential $targetUser -NamedArguments @{ClientDevice = "ClientName"}
```

Answer (score 2):

rcv.ps1

```
param(
    $username,
    $password
)

"The user is:  $username"
"My super secret password is:  $password"
```

execution from another script:

```
.\rcv.ps1 'user' 'supersecretpassword'
```

output:

```
The user is:  user
My super secret password is:  supersecretpassword
```

Comment: To clarify: the intent is not just to pass credentials, but to _run as_ the user identified by the credentials.

Comment: @mklement0, thanks for the clarification because that wasn't clear at all to me by the different iterations of the question being asked.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do it the following to pass a parameter to a ps1 script.

The first script can be a **origin.ps1** where we write:

```
& C:\scripts\dest.ps1 Pa$$w0rd parameter_a parameter_n
```

Th destination script **dest.ps1** can have the following code to capture the variables

```
$var0 = $args[0]
$var1 = $args[1]
$var2 = $args[2]
Write-Host "my args",$var0,",",$var1,",",$var2
```

And the result will be

```
my args Pa$$w0rd, parameter_a, parameter_n
```

Comment: The main goal is to combine all conditions into 1 execution. I have to pass parameters and to pass credentials!

Comment: What do you mean with "combine all conditions into 1 execution". I dont think you can add a parameter with the "-" symbol like you did.. I think you have to reformat the strings on the destination script

Comment: I must execute some PS1 file with parameters and pass `-Credential $credentials` parameter to this execution and get output from it into a variable. The ps1. Script im executing is throwing a singe word string at the end. Just look at the way I did it with `Start-process` but this function doesn't generate output

Comment: I think powershell doesn't allow you to pass a parameter like this $arguments = "C:\..\script1.ps1" + " -ClientName" + $DeviceName. You should probably think of deleting the "-"

Comment: that beeing said. Start-Process does execute the script with parameters and credentials, bit it doesn't save this output into a variable. If im trying to access `$output` variable, it's NULL. The other Idea that came from @mklement0 is to save output to a file. But in my case it will cause a huge amount of files in one place. All created from different users with different scripts

Comment: @AndyMcRae, `"C:\..\script1.ps1" + " -ClientName " + $DeviceName` constructs a _string_ representation of a PowerShell command that is passed as the only value to the `-ArgumentList` parameter of `Start-Process`, which passes it to `powershell.exe` in the new process, which works just fine (assuming the script path has no embedded spaces). Dmytro's challenge is to run a script_as a different user_ - hence `Start-Process -Credential` - while collecting output from that script _in memory_ rather than in _files_ (which `-RedirectStandardOutput` and `-RedirectStandardError` would allow you to do).

Comment: Ok now I get the point of that question.. I guess it has been answered though.