# RedirectStandardError $logFile with Append?

Tags: powershell, logging, append, start-process

I have a PowerShell script where I use Start-Process and redirect output to a log file.  The cmd is in a for loop, and I'd like to have the output append each time it runs. Right now it wipes out the log file each time it runs.  Is there a way to redirect and append?

```
Start-Process $cmd -ArgumentList $cmdArgs -RedirectStandardError $logFile -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

Answer (score 2):

Note: **To *synchronously* execute *console applications*, call them *directly* (`c:\path\to\some.exe ...` or `& $exePath ...`), do *not* use `Start-Process`** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334633/45375); that way, you can capture their output directly with `$ouput = c:\path\to\some.exe ...` or **append their output to an existing file with `>>` or by piping to `Add-Content`<sup>[1]</sup>** - see [`about_Redirection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection)

- Use redirection `2>&1` in combination with `>> $logFile` to *also* capture standard error output, along with standard output.

```
& $cmd $cmdArgs 2>&1 >> $logFile
```

- Use redirection `2>> $logFile` to capture *only* standard error output.

```
& $cmd $cmdArgs 2>> $logFile
```

The rest of this answer addresses the question *as asked*:

---

**No, (as of PowerShell 7.0) there's no way to *append* to preexisting files with [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process)'

`-RedirectStandardOutput` and `-RedirectStandardError` parameters** - they invariably *replace* the specified output files.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60889925/45375) shows how to use the underlying .NET API directly, allowing you to collect the process' output *in memory*, which then allows you to append that to an existing file (e.g., with
[`Add-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Add-Content)).

However, as [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60908474/45375) shows, using an auxiliary temporary file with
`-RedirectStandardError`, whose content is later appended to the overall output file is probably the simplest solution.

---

<sup>[1] `>>` blindly applies `Out-File`'s default encoding, which is UTF-16LE ("Unicode") in *Windows PowerShell*, and BOM-less UTF-8 in PowerShell [Core] 6+; `Add-Content`, by contrast, tries to match the target file's preeexisting encoding.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for your responses.  I decided to go with my own alternative, which was to send the output from each Start-Process job to a temporary log file, and then copy the data from the temp log file into my primary log file.  Not nearly as elegant, but simple enough and it works.

```
$logFile = "C:\work\myLogFile.log"
$logFileTemp = "C:\work\myTempLogFile.log"
Start-Process $cmd -ArgumentList $cmdArgs -RedirectStandardError $logFileTemp -Wait -NoNewWindow
Get-Content $logFileTemp | Out-File $logFile -Append
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can get away with just calling the cmd directly, you can try with `2>>`:

```
&$cmd 2>> $logFile
```

See [SS64](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-redirection.html) for more details:

> command 2>> filename    # APPEND errors to a file