# Executing elevated powershell scripts from C# in .NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, powershell, networking, .net-core

I'm calling a self-elevating powershell script from C# code. The Script resets DNS Settings.
The script works fine when called from unelevated powershell, but takes no effect when called from C# code with no exceptions thrown.
My Execution policy is temporarily set on unrestricted and I'm running Visual Studio as Admin.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

**The C#:**

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var pathToScript = @"C:\Temp\test.ps1";
        Execute(pathToScript);

        Console.ReadKey();


    }
    public static void Execute(string command)
    {
        using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            var results = ps.AddScript(command).Invoke();
            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
            }
        }
    }


}
```

**The script:**

```
# Get the ID and security principal of the current user account
$myWindowsID = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent();
$myWindowsPrincipal = New-Object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($myWindowsID);

# Get the security principal for the administrator role
$adminRole = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator;

# Check to see if we are currently running as an administrator
if ($myWindowsPrincipal.IsInRole($adminRole))
{
    # We are running as an administrator, so change the title and background colour to indicate this
    $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition + "(Elevated)";
    $Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor = "DarkBlue";
    Clear-Host;
}
else {
    # We are not running as an administrator, so relaunch as administrator

    # Create a new process object that starts PowerShell
    $newProcess = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo "PowerShell";

    # Specify the current script path and name as a parameter with added scope and support for scripts with spaces in it's path
    $newProcess.Arguments = "& '" + $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path + "'"

    # Indicate that the process should be elevated
    $newProcess.Verb = "runas";

    # Start the new process
    [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($newProcess);

    # Exit from the current, unelevated, process
    Exit;
}

# Run your code that needs to be elevated here...
Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex 9 -ResetServerAddresses
```

Comment: VS doesn't automatically run AS ADMIN.  The code will run from .exe file correctly.  To run from VS, create a shortcut to VS.  Then right click shortcut and select RUN AS ADMIN.

Comment: I'm running as admin already. Sorry forgot to mention

Comment: If you are connecting to a remote machine you need admin on both local and remote.  Then any paths you need the dollar sign like //myserver/c$

Comment: No remote machine, all of this is done locally.

Comment: The communication between the c# and Power shell are through streams (see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershellstreamtype?view=pscore-6.2.0).  How do you plan to do the communications?  How are you planning to wait  in c# for PowerShell to complete?  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell?view=pscore-6.2.0

Comment: I just got this to work by adding "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File" before the script. Thank you anyways!

Comment: Just an aside: `;` is only ever necessary in PowerShell code if you place _multiple_ commands on the same line.

Answer (score 5):

As you've just determined yourself, the primary **problem was that script execution was disabled on your system**, necessitating (at least) a process-level change of PowerShell's [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies), as the following C# code demonstrates, which calls
[`Set-ExecutionPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy)  `-Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass` before invoking the script file (`*.ps1`):

- For an **alternative approach that uses the *initial session state* to set the *per-process* execution policy**, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68942672/45375).
- The **approach below can in principle be used to *persistently* change the execution policy *for the current user***, namely by replacing `.AddParameter("Scope", "Process")` with `.AddParameter("Scope", "CurrentUser")`

  - *Caveat*: When using a *PowerShell (Core) 7+* SDK, persistent changes to the *local machine*'s policy (`.AddParameter("Scope", "LocalMachine")`) - which require running *with elevation* (as admin) - are seen *by that SDK project only*; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69534341/45375) for details.

*Caveat*: If the current user's / machine's execution policy is controlled by a *GPO* (Group Policy Object), it can NOT be overridden programmatically - neither per process, nor persistently (except via GPO changes).

```cs
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

      var pathToScript = @"C:\Temp\test.ps1";
      Execute(pathToScript);

      Console.ReadKey();

    }

    public static void Execute(string command)
    {
      using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
      {

        // Make sure that script execution is enabled at least for 
        // the current process.
        // For extra safety, you could try to save and restore
        // the policy previously in effect after executing your script.
        ps.AddCommand("Set-ExecutionPolicy")
          .AddParameter("Scope", "Process")
          .AddParameter("ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass")
          .Invoke();

        // Now invoke the script and print its success output.
        // Note: Use .AddCommand() (rather than .AddScript()) even
        //       for script *files*.
        //       .AddScript() is meant for *strings 
        //       containing PowerShell statements*.
        var results = ps.AddCommand(command).Invoke();
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
        }

        // Also report non-terminating errors, if any.
        foreach (var error in ps.Streams.Error)
        {
          Console.Error.WriteLine("ERROR: " + error.ToString());
        }

      }
    }

  }
```

Note that the **code also reports any non-terminating errors** that the script may have reported, via stderr (the standard error output stream).

Without the `Set-ExecutionPolicy` call, if the execution policy didn't permit (unsigned) script execution, PowerShell would report a *non-terminating error* via its *error stream* (`.Streams.Error`)  rather than throw an *exception*.

If you had checked `.Streams.Error` to begin with, you would have discovered the specific cause of your problem sooner.

Therefore:

- **When using the PowerShell SDK, *in addition to* relying on / catching exceptions, you must examine `.Streams.Error` to determine if (at least *formally* less severe) errors occurred.**

---

**Potential issues with your PowerShell script:**

- You're not waiting for the elevated process to terminate before returning from your PowerShell script.
- You're not capturing the elevated process' output, which you'd have to via the `.RedirectStandardInput` and `.RedirectStandardError` properties of the [`System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo) instance, and then make your script output the results.
- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60889925/45375) for how to do that.

The following, streamlined version of your code addresses the first point, and invokes the `powershell.exe` [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) via `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` too.

- If you're using the *Windows PowerShell* SDK, this shouldn't be necessary (because the execution policy was already changed in the C# code), but it could be if you're using the *PowerShell [Core]* SDK, given that the two PowerShell editions have separate execution-policy settings.

```sh
# Check to see if we are currently running as an administrator
$isElevated = & { net session *>$null; $LASTEXITCODE -eq 0 }
if ($isElevated)
{
    # We are running as an administrator, so change the title and background color to indicate this
    $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition + "(Elevated)"
    $Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor = "DarkBlue"
    Clear-Host
}
else {
    # We are not running as an administrator, so relaunch as administrator

    # Create a new process object that starts PowerShell
    $psi = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo 'powershell.exe'

    # Specify the current script path and name as a parameter with and support for scripts with spaces in its path
    $psi.Arguments = '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "{0}"' -f 
                     $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

    # Indicate that the process should be elevated.
    $psi.Verb = 'RunAs'
    # !! For .Verb to be honored, .UseShellExecute must be $true
    # !! In .NET Framework, .UseShellExecute *defaults* to $true,
    # !! but no longer in .NET Core.
    $psi.UseShellExecute = $true 

    # Start the new process, wait for it to terminate, then
    # exit from the current, unelevated process, passing the exit code through.
    exit $(
     try { ([System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($psi).WaitForExit()) } catch { Throw }
    )

}

# Run your code that needs to be elevated here...
Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex 9 -ResetServerAddresses
```