# C# PowerShell Script not working with ExecutionPolicy

Tags: c#, powershell, executionpolicy

I´m trying to run a PowerShell script with C# on .netCore.

I have tried many different solutions for now, but none of them seem to work. I just want to execute a PowerShell script and set ExecutionPolicies and Scope to make it work.
But I always got the exception that the ExecutionPolicies don´t allow me to run the script that way.

Despite that with the actual configuration and code, you find below, I don´t get any feedback from the Debugger after reaching the point where **.Invoke();** is executed. And waiting for response and letting the software doing its stuff in background leads always to a stackoverflow exception.

**commandParameters is a simple Dictionary<string, string>**

Any thoughts on this?

Cheers.

---

```
var iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault2();
        // Set its script-file execution policy.
        iss.ExecutionPolicy = Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy.Unrestricted;
        iss.ExecutionPolicy = (ExecutionPolicy)Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicyScope.CurrentUser;

        // Create a PowerShell instance with a runspace based on the 
        // initial session state.
        PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create(iss);

 ps.AddCommand(path + "\\" + fileName);
        ps.AddParameters(commandParameters);
        var results = ps.InvokeAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: You need to use Execution policy as RemoteSingned. Or you can bypass it

Comment: I am using Cake.PowerShell (1.0.1). I updated the function from Command to Script but that doen´t make any difference.

Answer (score 3):

- **Assigning to `iss.ExecutionPolicy` only ever controls the execution policy for the *current process***.
- **Do *not* assign a [`Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicyScope`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicyScope) value, as it is an *unrelated* enumeration** that defines the execution-policy *scope*, relevant only to the [`Set-ExecutionPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy) and [`Get-ExecutionPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-executionpolicy) cmdlets. The *numeric values* of this unrelated enumeration just so happen to overlap with the appropriate [`[Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy) enumeration values, so that policy *scope* `CurrentUser` maps onto *policy* `RemoteSigned` (value `0x1`).

  - In effect, your *second* `iss.ExecutionPolicy = ...` assignment *overrides* the first one and sets the *process-scope* execution policy to `RemoteSigned`.
  - The *process-scope* execution policy, i.e. for the *current process only*, is the only one you can set via an initial session state; see the next section for how to change policies for *persistent* scopes.

Therefore, **`iss.ExecutionPolicy = Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy.Unrestricted;` *alone* is enough to invoke `*.ps1` files in the session at hand** - *remove* the *second* `iss.ExecutionPolicy = ...` assignment.

---

**If you want to modify the execution policy *persistently***, you must use `.AddCommand('Set-ExecutionPolicy')` with the appropriate arguments and *invoke* that command. **Caveat**:

- Changing the persistent *current-user* configuration also takes effect for *regular* PowerShell sessions (interactive ones / CLI calls) in the respective PowerShell edition.
- By contrast, if you change the persistent *machine* configuration - which requires running *with elevation* (as admin):

  - With the *Windows PowerShell* SDK, the change also takes effect for regular PowerShell sessions.
  - With the *PowerShell (Core)* SDK, it only takes effect *for the SDK project at hand*.<sup>[1]</sup>
- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61141264/45375) for sample code.

**Caveat**:

- **If the current user's / machine's execution policy is controlled via *GPOs* (Group Policy Objects), you fundamentally cannot override it programmatically** (except via GPO changes).
- **To check if a GPO-based policy is in effect**:

  - Run [`Get-ExecutionPolicy -List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-executionpolicy) to list policies defined for each available scope, in descending order of precedence.
  - If either the `MachinePolicy` or the `UserPolicy` scope have a value *other* than `Undefined`, then a GPO policy is in effect (run `Get-ExecutionPolicy` without arguments to see the effective policy for the current session).

---

**Limited workaround for when a GPO-based policy prevents script-file execution**:

Assuming *all* of the following; *script file* refers to `*.ps1` files:

- Your script file calls no *other* script files.
- It (directly or indirectly) loads no modules that on import happen to call script files.
- Your script file doesn't rely on knowing its own location (directory) or name on disk.

You can load your script file's *content* into a *string* and pass that string to the SDK's [`.AddScript()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.AddScript) method, as the following simplified example shows:

```
using (var ps = PowerShell.Create()) {

  var results =
    ps.AddScript(File.ReadAllText(path + "\\" + fileName))
      .AddParameters(commandParameters)
      .Invoke();

}
```

---

<sup>[1] *Windows PowerShell* stores the execution policies in the *registry*, which both regular sessions and the SDK consult. By contrast, *PowerShell (Core)* stores them in `powershell.config.json` files, and in the case of the *machine* policy *alongside the PowerShell executable (DLL)*. Since SDK projects have their own executable, its attendant JSON file is *not* seen by the executable of a regular PowerShell (Core) installation.</sup>

Comment: ok then it won´t work that way. Because in that powershell script I want to use Azure cli to create and delete DataPools.

Comment: @Only3lue, calling a CLI (an external program or _non-PowerShell_ script file) shouldn't be a problem, though - it is only `*.ps1` files that are subject to the effective execution policy.