# Catch output from function running as different user

Tags: powershell

```
function Get-WSLIP {
wsl -- ip -o -4 -json addr list eth0 `
| ConvertFrom-Json `
| %{ $_.addr_info.local } `
| ?{ $_ }
}
```

I have this function I want to run as a different user where WSL is installed and catch the output by assigning this function to a variable.

I've tried `runas`, but it seems it wants to open a second process and I was unable to catch the output.

Comment: Maybe try `Invoke-Command`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Launching a process with a *different user identity* invariably launches the process *in a new window*** on Windows, which means that **you cannot *directly* capture that process' output**.

You have two options:

- **Use the [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process) API directly**, which **allows you to capture the process' output *in memory***, as *text*, via the `.RedirectStandardOutput` (and `.RedirectStandardError`) properties of the [`System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo) class.

  - This approach is **nontrivial**, especially if you want to also capture *stderr* output without the risk of deadlocks; a *stdout-output-only*-capturing solution can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60889925/45375).
  - It **precludes running the process *hidden***, because the use of another user's credentials (`.UserName` and `.PassWord` properties) requires that `.UseShellExecute` be `$false`, which in turn means that the `.WindowStyle` property is *ignored*.
- **Use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) if you want (the option) to run the process *hidden***, although that **requires the use of a *temporary file* to capture the output**:

  - **Pitfalls**: You **must ensure that the target user has permission**:

    - to access the  *working directory* of the newly launched process, which requires passing a suitable directory to `-WorkingDirectory`
    - to write to the (temporary) file path passed to `-RedirectStandardOutput` / `-RedirectStandardError`.
  - Note that `-RedirectStandardOutput` / `-RedirectStandardError` capture the output from the named streams *separately*, and must be *separate* files. If you want to *merge* the streams and capture them *interleaved* in a single file, you must launch your process via a *shell* (such as PowerShell or `cmd.exe`) and use *its* stream-merging features, typically `2>&1`.

The following **`Start-Process`-based solution** shows how to run the process hidden and capture stdout output (only):

```
# Prompt for the target user's credentials.
$cred = Get-Credential

# Determine the working directory and temporary file path.
# IMPORTANT: THE TARGET USER MUST HAVE PERMISSION TO
#  * ACCESS the working directory
#  * access and WRITE TO the temp file.
$workingDir = "$env:SystemRoot\Temp"
$tmpFile = Join-Path "$env:SystemRoot\Temp" "~$PID.tmp"

# Launch the process as the target user, hidden, save its stdout
# to the temporary file, and wait for it to terminate.
(Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden -PassThru -WorkingDirectory $workingDir -RedirectStandardOutput $tmpFile -Credential $cred powershell.exe @'
  -noprofile -command
  "[array] (wsl -- ip -o -4 -json addr list eth0 | ConvertFrom-Json).addr_info.local -ne ''"
'@).WaitForExit()

# Get the captured output and remove the temp. file.
$output = Get-Content $tmpFile; Remove-Item $tmpFile

# Print the captured result
$output
```

Note:

- The `powershell.exe` [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) call above uses a streamlined version of the command in your question.
- While `Start-Process` has a dedicated `-Wait` switch to await the launched process' termination, as of PowerShell Core 7.2 it appears to be incompatible with `-Credential`, i.e. with running as a different user (resulting in an `Access denied` error while still launching the process, albeit *asynchronously*).

  - The workaround is to use `-PassThru`, in order to make the normally output-less `Start-Process` emit a `System.Diagnostics.Process` instance describing the launched process, and call `.WaitForExit()` on that instance.

Comment: Extreme solution definetily not what I expected, but it works. I accepted. So I guess its not the norm on Windows to capture output from a different user. How can one securely save credentials for running this via task scheduler for example?

Comment: @dza, for a reasonably secure Windows solution for saving credentials, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40029496/45375). The [`Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretManagement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.secretmanagement/?view=ps-modules) module may be an alternative. Task Scheduler, specifically, allows you to specify and persist credentials too.

Comment: Yes, the reason is I need to run as Administrator to set firewall permission and regular user to grab WSL IP.

Comment: @dza, actually, to run _with elevation_ (as administrator), you need to use `Start-Process -Verb RunAs`, and in this case the only way to avoid an interactive confirmation / password prompt is to use a scheduled task with preconfigured admin credentials that non-admin users can invoke on demand.

Comment: Cool thanks for that tip. I still have the issue of needing the users running WSL IP which is not available as Administrator.